# Does store.loadData fires load event on the store on ExtJs 4.2.5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

**Does store.loadData fires load event on the store on ExtJs 4.2.5 ?**

The documentation states it does: http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData

But given what I've experienced it doesn't look like it does and also looking at the source code:

```
loadData: function(data, append) {
    var length = data.length,
        newData = [],
        i;

    //make sure each data element is an Ext.data.Model instance
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        newData.push(this.createModel(data[i]));
    }

    this.loadRecords(newData, append ? this.addRecordsOptions : undefined);
},
```

ok so probably loadRecords is firing it right?

```
loadRecords: function(records, options) {
    var me     = this,
        i      = 0,
        length = records.length,
        start,
        addRecords,
        snapshot = me.snapshot;

    if (options) {
        start = options.start;
        addRecords = options.addRecords;
    }

    if (!addRecords) {
        delete me.snapshot;
        me.clearData(true);
    } else if (snapshot) {
        snapshot.addAll(records);
    }

    me.data.addAll(records);

    if (start !== undefined) {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            records[i].index = start + i;
            records[i].join(me);
        }
    } else {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            records[i].join(me);
        }
    }

    /*
     * this rather inelegant suspension and resumption of events is required because both the filter and sort functions
     * fire an additional datachanged event, which is not wanted. Ideally we would do this a different way. The first
     * datachanged event is fired by the call to this.add, above.
     */
    me.suspendEvents();

    if (me.filterOnLoad && !me.remoteFilter) {
        me.filter();
    }

    if (me.sortOnLoad && !me.remoteSort) {
        me.sort();
    }

    me.resumeEvents();
    if (me.isGrouped()) {
        me.constructGroups();
    }
    me.fireEvent('datachanged', me);
    me.fireEvent('refresh', me);
},
```

It's not fired there either.

**Is this a known issue or am I missing something ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadData` does not fire the `load` event, because the `load` event fires whenever the store reads data from a **remote** data source ([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load)). `loadData` works with **local** data provided in its first argument.

You've found an inaccuracy in the documentation. I followed your research in version 4.1.1 and I couldn't find `loadData` firing the `load` event there.

However `loadRawData` used to fire the `load` event in 4.1.1, but it doesn't anymore in 4.2.5. In the [source code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-loadRawData) you can read:

*As of 4.2, this (loadRawData) method will no longer fire the {@link #event-load} event.*

Comment: What about the link and the argument I talked about http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData it seems that it is stated that it does fire the load event. Also in previous versions it was firing it (4.1.1). But that doesn't seem to be the case on 4.2.5 although I think the docs suggest otherwise.

Comment: I assumed it was being fired previously because the issue that I'm facing by not having that event fired is only present on 4.2.5 ... But yeah I think it's more of a doc inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can bank on Refresh event, look at this example I've created which demonstrate the usage

[Refresh](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16us)!